# Docker container not showing any outputs

Tags: docker

I have a pretty simple docker file that is based on an Ubuntu image, asks the user for his/her name and prints it using Figlet. However, after I built the image and ran the container, it doesn't show me anything.

**Dockerfile**:

```
# Download the base image ubuntu
FROM ubuntu

# Update
RUN apt-get update

# Install figlet
RUN apt-get install figlet

# Copy program
COPY program.sh /

# Execute
RUN /program.sh
```

**Program.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ask user for name
echo 'Please enter your name: '
read username

# Print name
figlet $username
```

It seems to build and run without any issue. I just can't see anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean the last line of the Dockerfile to be `CMD`, so that your script is the thing that runs when the container starts?  `RUN` will run only once during the image build and can't accept interactive input.

Comment: Containers don't run in an interactive mode  by default. If you want an interactive shell that takes your input and shows the output you need to use `-it` flag. Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/).

Answer (score 2):

```
RUN
```

Is instruction that runs during build time and you can't read input during build.

If you want it to run when you run

```
docker run ...
```

Use

```
CMD /program.sh 
# Or 
ENTRYPOINT /program.sh
```

P.S.
As @super commented you must use `-it` flag in `docker run` command to be able to read user input. 
As @oreopot answered your script must have execute permissions.

Answer (score 1):

After `COPY` and before the `RUN` command in your dockerfile, add the following command:

We are giving the execute permission to `program.sh`

```
RUN chmod +x /program.sh
```